# Print the integers from 1 to a number given by user

Tags: java

I'm doing the Java MOOC by Helsinki University. Stuck on the following problem:

Write a program which prints the integers from 1 to a number given by the user.

Sample output

```
Where to? 3
1
2
3
```

The code below outputs the expected results but is not accepted as valid. Any suggestions or pointers are welcome, thank you!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class FromWhereToWhere {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Write your program here
        System.out.println("Where to?");
        int userInput = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        int start = 1;
       
        while (start <= userInput) {
            System.out.println(start);
            start++;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `scanner.nextInt()` instead of `Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine())`

Comment: Is a new line character required (is `123` accepted)? If not, how is your program validated?

Comment: Was there any reason why the code is considered invalid? Could be the possible resource leak due to not closing the `Scanner` instance. Or do you have to use a `for` loop?

Comment: Do you have any input constraints? for example what should happen if input is `-1`?

Comment: @deHaar actually, closing scanner is bad here; that would close standard in, you usually do not want to close that.

Comment: Not to mention that the Scanner is automatically closed when the program ends.

Comment: @dan1st I tried that but still not accepted.

Comment: The proposal by @dan makes the program more robust against input which does not ONLY contain an int. Maybe some test cases are like "5 haha", or "5 1". Both of which fail with your code but succeed with the proposal.

Comment: Perhaps the format of the output is wrong.

Comment: @rzwitserloot ok, sure, it's in the `main` and will be closed at program termination. Eclipse still warns about open resources using this code.

Comment: Output might be subtly wrong. Try `System.out.print("Where to?");`. which should remove a newline before the "3" from input. (Which I now realise is part of the answer below....)

Comment: @Glains yes new line is preferable and it is validated by sending my results to the Helsinki server. I am told: "FAIL: WhereFromTest test -With the input 12, 8 output should contain 5 numbers, now it contained 12" which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @deHaar There is no instruction to use for or while loop, I can use either.

Comment: @Ecto I believe that input should be above 1 from the instructions.

Comment: I would suggest considering edge cases, such as negative input, char/s input, very big number input (bigger than int), etc.

Comment: It seems to me that you are solving the wrong problem. You wrote a program printing 1 to n, but the class is named "FromWhereToWhere" and the error message says the input is two numbers.

Comment: @kaya3 You're right! The first bit of the code was validated but since it was two parts to the test it marked the whole exercise as a fail. The instructions did say that I could submit only the 1st part though. 

Thank you and sorry all for this oversight!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the system that tests your program is stuffing values into standard input (`System.in`) with spaces, and assumes that you will read with `.nextInt()`.

If that's not it, double check the program description; what is supposed to happen if I enter -1? 0? 1985985410395831490583440958230598? FOOBAR?

If it doesn't say, then presumably the verifier won't throw those inputs at you (if it does, file a bug with the MOOC provider, the course itself needs fixing if that is the case), but if it does, you're going to have to code those rules in, probably.

This shouldn't be it, but to exactly mirror the desired result, it's `System.out.print("Where to? ");` - note, no `ln`, and a trailing space.

Comment: `This shouldn't be it` Why not?

Comment: The question should either make crystal clear it needs to look exactly like that, or, the MOOC's verifier should ignore this part, because, well, duh?

Comment: The expected output states no line break.

Answer (score 1):

You did not check if the user input is valid, I would suggest starting off with the following:

1. check if userInput is a valid number (includes numeric characters).
2. check if userInput is larger or equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

your answer is ok but can be optimized to the beginners levels if that is what your teacher is expecting because:

1. you can get an int directly from scanner, no need to use the wrapper class Integer.
2. you can use another loop ... a for loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Write your program here
    System.out.println("Where to?");
    int userInput = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("ok!");
    for (int i = 1; i <= userInput; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try by Removing
System.out.println("Where to?");
with
System.out.print("Where to?");